# Code is working fine everywhere except IE, can't figure out why

Tags: javascript

I have simple script that slides certain blocks on scroll. It seems to work perfectly fine on every browser except IE and I can not figure out why. I compiled the code using babel to ECMA5 hoping that it would help, but it won't.

This is the JS

```
function slideIn(e) {
    sliderImages.forEach(function (sliderImage) {
        var slideInAt = window.scrollY + window.innerHeight;
        var imageBottom = sliderImage.offsetTop + sliderImage.offsetHeight;
        var isHalfShown = slideInAt > sliderImage.offsetTop;
        var isNotScrolledPast = window.scrollY < imageBottom;
        if (isHalfShown && isNotScrolledPast) {
            sliderImage.classList.add('visible');
        } else {
            sliderImage.classList.remove('visible');
        }
    });
}
```

If anyone has ever had similar problem and knows what it could be related to that would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Use [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) instead as a progressive enhancement. (Some might argue sliding things in on scroll isn’t an enhancement, but the same principle applies.)

Comment: I appreciate the comment, but in the link you've provided it says that none of it is supported on IE.

Comment: Correct, the idea is to pass up the animation on IE. Just have the content visible all the time.

Comment: ClassList is not supported on InternetExplorer.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not an error. What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Lionel - it simply is not doing anything. The idea is that specific blocks are hidden with some css, and on scroll 'animated' class is added to those blocks and they slide in. However, on IE they just stay invisible, as if the script is not running.

Comment: As @Carlos1232 has pointed out, IE does not support classList, well, not on <IE9 and only partially it seems on IE10/11 (see caniuse.com). IE9 upwards does support className and you can use this to substitute when classList is not available. I'll post some code which does this.

Comment: What do you mean by window.scrollY ? That's a Netscape proprietary property.

Answer (score 0):

The question is why aren't the slides sliding in and out in IE but are OK on some other browsers.

The code given uses classList and this is not available (or at least not fully) on IE as @Carlos1232 commented. This is probably the only IE problem looking at the given code.

You can substitute these lines:

```
sliderImage.classList.add('visible');

sliderImage.classList.remove('visible');
```

with

```
add(sliderImage,'visible');

remove(sliderImage,'visible');
```

if you add the two functions below. They check whether classList is implemented in the browser, and if it isn't they instead get the className (which is OK on IE>=9) and parse the string it contains to add/remove the required class.

```
function add(element,cl) {
  if (element.classList) {
    element.classList.add(cl);
  }
  else {
    if (element.className.split(" ").indexOf(cl) == -1) {
      element.className += " " + cl;
    }
  }
}

function remove(element,cl) {
  if (element.classList) {
    element.classList.remove(cl);
  }
  else {
    element.className = element.className.replace(/\bcl\b/g, "");
  }
}
```